# Simple while loop query in Javascript

Tags: javascript, this

In the book Beginning javascript i came across a simple program which is written below. I am unable to understand how the this/that code works here and how the while loop operates here ( I know while loops a little but the **!= - 1** part makes it confusing & the google search i did on it turned out a little vague). Any help is appreciated and if there is any mistake please feel free to correct it. I can understand what the code below is doing but the above query are still a little confusing
*The simple code below is working*.

**Code:**

```js
var myImages = new Array("monkeyDluffy.png", "roronoaZoro.jpg", "sanji.jpg", "godUssop.png");

function changeImg(that) { //Can be named anything that is just professional
  var newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3); //a simple random number generated
  while (that.src.indexOf(myImages[newImgNumber]) != -1) {
    newImgNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
  }
  that.src = myImages[newImgNumber];

  return false;
}
/*here use of this and that enables the code to perform better for a single object as*/
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JS</title>

  <body>
    <img src="monkeyDluffy.png" onclick="return changeImg(this)" />
    <img src="roronoaZoro.jpg" onclick="return changeImg(this)" />
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: The `!= -1` means "Does not equal negative 1." The function `indexOf()` will tell you the *index* of a string, which is 0-based. Meaning, if you did an `"hello world".indexOf("h")`, you'd get **0**, because h is the first character. `-1` means that the string is *not found*.

Answer (score 3):

> the != - 1 part makes it confusing

Look at [the documentation for `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

> Return value
>
> The index of the first occurrence of the specified value; -1 if not
>   found.

So it loops while the specified value is found. When it isn't found, the loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

The check ( != -1 ) simply means that, if the searched value can be found in the source ( Array in this case ) , the code should continue looping , that is, it should run the code in the body of the **while** loop.

The  consfusion that you have with the **this / that** concept:

this means the current context or the context to refer to when working with objects and this can really be confusing as JavaScript has things like anonymous functions and functions calling other functions, which leads to 'loss' of context or confusion of what exactly the **this** keyword binds or refers to, but that is another topic.

In your case, the call of the changeImg function as depicted in your code **`return changeImg(this)`** allows the passing of **this** as argument(s) which helps set the context to the current element ( DOM element ) being clicked, so that you can access it in your Js code. So you can look at the passing of **this** as a way of making sure that as much as you'll be calling the same function ( changeImg ) on different elements, the context is correctly set.

The use of **that** , is simply a way of referring to **this** , I would assume that, somewhere in your textbook, where you extracted the code from, there's something that probably looks like : `var that = this;`

Answer (score 0):

'this' is referring to the img element, 'that' is a function argument, so 'that' refers to whatever object is passed in there (which happens to be the same object as 'this').

and then also the stuff Quentin said.

Answer (score 0):

'this' specified on

```
<img src="monkeyDluffy.png" onclick="return changeImg(this)" />
```

will refer to the 'img' element in your 'changeImg' function: for this reason you can access directly to "src" property.
'that' simply is the method parameter and will refer to 'this'.

For insteadOf return method, the Quentin's answer is good!